# Best way to build communication between redux libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

We are trying to split our project on to pieces:

We have libraries e.g **user-library** and **image-library**.
Each library has their own reducer, and actions e.g:

**for user-library:**

```
{isloggein: false} // store

function logIn() { //action creator 
    return {
        type: 'LOGIN'
    };
}
```

**for image-library:**

```
{images: []} // store

function addImages() { //action creator 
    return {
        type: 'ADDIMAGES'
    };
}
```

Now we decide that we want **addImages** as soon as user **logIn**. Problem is image store now nothing about user actions (that is main idea of code splitting). We solved that problem by using sagas like this:

```
function* addImagesWhenLogIn() {
    while (true) {
        yield take('LOGIN');
        yield put(addImages());
    }
}
```

But it is not opaque (we dispatched one action but 2 actions will be dispatch actually). While it is fine to have business logic of application in sagas, I believe that **take -> put** sequence is not the best solution in such case, and I am looking for better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the advantages of redux architecture is the capability to easy hydration, snapshots, time travel, and it works best if there is a single place where state is stored.

From redux docs:

> Single source of truth - The state of your whole application is stored
>   in an object tree within a single store. [Ref](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html).

Therefore a unique state for your redux app is recommended.

In your case I would suggest:

- You could keep separated your libraries/modules, import them as you need in your app.
- Use only a single state tree as suggested in redux docs.
- Provide state information to your representational components using [containers](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a perfectly valid approach.  Your two main options are to either have one module import action creators from the other module (thus somewhat coupling the two directly), or have a separate piece of code that glues the two together.  Using a saga like that is a very good approach for handling the "glue" aspect.